# MySQL True vs False optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing

Can someone explain to me why I'm seeing the following behavior:

```
mysql> show index from history_historyentry;
+----------------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| Table                | Non_unique | Key_name                     | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment |
+----------------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
| history_historyentry |          0 | PRIMARY                      |            1 | id          | A         |       48609 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |  
+----------------------+------------+------------------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `history_historyentry`  WHERE `history_historyentry`.`is_deleted` = False;
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | history_historyentry | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 48612 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `history_historyentry`  WHERE `history_historyentry`.`is_deleted` = True;
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | history_historyentry | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 48613 | Using where | 
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create index deleted on history_historyentry (is_deleted) ;
Query OK, 48627 rows affected (0.38 sec)
Records: 48627  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `history_historyentry`  WHERE `history_historyentry`.`is_deleted` = False;
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | history_historyentry | index | deleted       | deleted | 1       | NULL | 36471 | Using where; Using index | 
+----+-------------+----------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `history_historyentry`  WHERE `history_historyentry`.`is_deleted` = True;
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | history_historyentry | ref  | deleted       | deleted | 1       | const |  166 | Using index | 
+----+-------------+----------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why the descrepancy in index usage for True vs False? Specifically, in the false case, the ref column is NULL, and the extra column is Using where; Using index. But in the true case, the ref column is const, and the extra column is Using index.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably because one gives good selectivity and the other does not, i.e. only a small percentage of the rows are deleted.

A cost based optimiser will only use an index if it provides good selectivity (typically 10%) or possibly if it is a covering index (one which satifies a query without a further table or bookmark lookup).

Comment: You can empirically verify that with a table that has the same amount of rows with is_deleted = True and with is_deleted = False

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Shouldn't it be solely using the index in either case though? You're right in that the deleted set is much smaller than the non-deleted set, but it wouldn't require anything more than just the index.

Comment: An index is used to filter rows; so unless using it results in significantly less rows,rather than scanning the index, the optimiser will ignore it and scan the table instead.